# ZendFramework2 Navigation with # added

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2

I'm working on a webpage in ZF2, where i need a few items in the menu using #.
I'm using the build Navigation, and i need a item that would look like.

http://webpage.com/blog/1#subscript

At this time my menu item looks like this

```
'Blog' => array(
  'label'     => 'News',
  'route'     => 'blog',
  'params'    => array('id'=>1),
 }
```

But i can't find this in the documentation.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `fragment` property in [abstrace page class](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.4/library/Zend/Navigation/Page/AbstractPage.php#L42), so you can set it via configuration like this:

```php
'Blog' => array(
    'label'    => 'News',
    'route'    => 'blog',
    'params'   => array('id' => 1),
    'fragment' => 'subscript',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why i didn't see that i don't know. Anyways thanks, you just saved my day